# How to hide duplicates values in column

Tags: jasper-reports

I have 2 tables in sql **`table_a`** and **`table_b`** this is the output: (1 to many relationship)

```
table_a                    table_b
id_no (pk)  name            id_no (fk)      id_tabl(pk)     order_code     order_item
1            a                1                 1              11              aple
1            a                1                 2              12              orange
1            a                1                 3              13              ice
2            b                2                 4              12              orange
2            b                2                 5              13              ice
3            c                3                 6              13              ice
3            c                3                 7              12              orange
3            c                3                 8              11              aple
```

I want to display only 1 name with all his ***`order_item`***.

How can I display it using `iReport` in the xml?

The output sample:

```
id_no      name    order_item
1           a       aple
                    orange
                    ice
2           b       orange
                    ice
3            c       ice
                    orange
                    aple
```

Using only 2 (***`order_item`***) field pattern in every pages of my invoice
the other display will be displayed in invoice pages 2.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `Data Grouping`.

You can read [this article](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/jasper/index.html#groups) about data grouping.

- Your can use the query like this:

```sql
SELECT table_a.id_no, table_a.name, table_b.order_item FROM table_a, table_b WHERE table_a.id_no=table_b.id_no ORDER BY table_a.name
```

*Note*: may be you need to add sort by *`table_a.id_no`* column.

- You should create the `iReport`'s group for the *`name`* field

*Note*: may be you need to create two groups - for *`id_no`* and *`name`* fields.

- You can use the `Group` and `Details` bands for drawing the data row. Or you can put all `textField` elements to the `Detail` band. In this case you should set `false` value to the ***`isPrintRepeatedValues`*** `textField`'s property (for *`id_no`* and *`name`* fields).